# ¿Porque mi aplicación no esta aplicando el tema de MD3 en su recycleview?

Tags: android, xml, material-design

Estoy trabajando con android studio para hacer una aplicación dónde guarde los datos usando SQLite, el problema no es la lógica para guardar datos si no más bien el tema es parte de la personalización de la app.

Estoy usando el tema de Material Design 3 de Google pero al correr la aplicación me está mostrando otro tema que no se de donde lo esta tomando, es decir..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí estoy usando los componentes de MD3 en la IDE no muestra ningún tipo de error, al menos en el XML, el código de la tarjeta es la siguiente:

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar"
    android:padding="@dimen/margin_8">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/card_h"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="@dimen/margin_8">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/guideline"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.8" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                style="?attr/materialIconButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:icon="@drawable/baseline_more_vert_24"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/str_card_title"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:text="@string/str_card_body"
                android:textAlignment="inherit"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

            <com.google.android.material.divider.MaterialDivider
                android:id="@+id/materialDivider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_download"
                style="@style/Widget.Material3.Button.ElevatedButton.Icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/str_btn_download"
                app:icon="@drawable/round_download_24"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

En el apartado del `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout` estoy insertando la propiedad de `android:theme="@style/Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar"` para poder usar el `com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView` La cosa es que el ActivityMain si me respeta el layout, en la siguiente imagen se ve que el archivo si esta respetando el tema pero en el Recycleview no lo esta tomando

[image: RecycleView]

Pero al correr me esta tomando otro tema que seria `AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`

[image: Material Theme]

Cheque cada uno de los archivos dónde se configura el tema, pero todo esta configurado con el tema de MD3, desde el `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Mvp_sqlite"
    tools:targetApi="31">
    <activity
        android:name=".view.MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Hasta los archivos de recurso de temas modo "Light"

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Base.Theme.Mvp_sqlite" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight">
    <!-- Customize your light theme here. -->
    <!-- <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_light_primary</item> -->
</style>

<style name="Theme.Mvp_sqlite" parent="Base.Theme.Mvp_sqlite" />
```

y modo "Dark"

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Base.Theme.Mvp_sqlite" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight">
    <!-- Customize your dark theme here. -->
    <!-- <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_dark_primary</item> -->
</style>
```

La cosa es que ya no se dónde más seguir configurando, sí alguien puede ayudarme porfavor

Comment: Hola. Muestra el `.xml` donde declaras tu RecyclerView, puede que allí estés indicando otro estilo. Revisa también en `res/values/styles.xml` y/o en `res/values/themes.xml` si no estás indicando estilos diferentes para los elementos implicados.

Comment: Ya vi cual era el detalle, no era el archivo de temas que se estaba aplicando si no que en el ```item_pedido.xml``` estaba usando el botón nativo de android,  por lo que tuve que cambiar de ```<button/>``` a ```<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton>``` ese era el problema por  la cual en el recycleview intentaba interpretar el estilo del botón con la propiedad de ```style="@style/Widget.Material3.Button.ElevatedButton.Icon"``` y no se lo aplicaba.

Answer (score 0):

El problema se encontraba aquí, estaba usando el botón nativo de android y la vez aplicando el estilo de MD3, nesecitaba usar la etiqueta `com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton` para que lo aplicara.

```
            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_download"
            style="@style/Widget.Material3.Button.ElevatedButton.Icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/str_btn_download"
            app:icon="@drawable/round_download_24"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
```